# Tkinter: How to get event listener when entry box is deselected?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, events, listener

Just the title. I have an entry box that needs to be rounded to 10, but I want it to happen the moment another entry box is selected.

The only event listener I can find to do with tkinter entry boxes is attatching a StringVar and tracing it, but that doesn't seem to do what I want here as I don't want the changes to happen while typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `<FocusOut>` event.

```
def some_func(event):
    print("The entry has lost focus")
entry = tk.Entry(...)
entry.bind("<FocusOut>", some_func)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to send parameters to this, without it being called on program launch?

I.e. I want to use:
```
entryDx.bind("<FocusOut>",round_floor_ten(variable_id))
```
but when I do that, the round_floor_ten function is called when the code is loaded.
function is defined as:
```
def round_floor_ten(*args):
```

Comment: @Frogglet: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared